# stuck with jquery radio button checked / click

Tags: jquery

first timer here especially to jquery, I've got a review form written in php with mysql. Part of the form allows the user to re-edit the details if they press the preview button. The below is what is in use to show / hide a few of the fields depending on which radio button is checked further up the form (this all works as expected).

When you press preview though without filling in some of the fields, the below no longer works, as the form posts to itself and there's a variable which inputs checked into the radio button the user selected, to save the user from filling it in again. The problem is though as their not clicking the radio again the remaining fields lower down aren't being displayed. What I really need the below to do is to check for the "checked" value and if its not present to then check for the click.

Either way I need the lower if statement to run. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
$("input[name$='business_group']").click(function(){

    var radio_value = $(this).val();

    if(radio_value=='accommodation') {
        $(".acc_title").show();
        $(".fd_title").hide();
    } else if(radio_value=='food_drink') {
        $(".acc_title").hide();
        $(".fd_title").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but check this link to see if it helps you

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

Anyway, I'm not so sure about the $ sign here:

```
$("input[name$='business_group']").click(function(){
```

Try to use this instead:

```
$("input[name='business_group']").click(function(){
```

Also, get sure that the event is being fired; put an alert after the click(function(){ }:

```
click(function(){ ... alert("Passed here"); ...}
```

or console.log if you are using Firebug

Comment: thanks for the advice, all I'm trying to do is to run the code above with either the “click” or with “checked” already set as a value. I've had a look at .attr('checked') but I'm not too sure how to implement it with the rest of the code.

Comment: found the answer in a different route: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212540/jquery-checked-checkbox-on-refresh-and-unique-value-query)