# jquery checked checkbox on refresh and unique value query

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a piece of code only when a `checkbox` is checked on refresh with the correct value?

```
if ($("input[name='business_group']").attr("checked")==true && .val("accommodation")) { 
    $(".acc_title").show();
    $(".fd_title").hide();
    $(".dest_title").hide();
    $(".ttt_title").hide();
    $(".c_name_container").show();
    $(".stay").show();
    $(".visit").hide();

    alert("accommodation checked"); 
} 
else if ($("input[name='business_group']").attr("checked")==true && .val("food_drink")) {   
    $(".fd_title").show();
    $(".acc_title").hide();
    $(".dest_title").hide();
    $(".ttt_title").hide();
    $(".c_name_container").show();
    $(".stay").hide();
    $(".visit").show();

    alert("food_drink checked");
}
```

Any idea why the above code doesn't work?

Comment: Simplify your code and add all code that matter (for example the HTML). And be more specific on your question.

Comment: Btw, you can post your code on jsfiddle.net for easier answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You jQuery code is slightly wrong, this should do what you want:

```
if ($("input[name='business_group']:checked").val() === "accommodation") {    
    // code here
} else if ($("input[name='business_group']:checked").val() === "food_drink") {
    // code here
}
```

Infact it would be better to save this value into a variable:

```
var checkedValue = $("input[name='business_group']:checked").val();
switch(checkedValue) {
    case "accommodation": // do stuff; break;
    case "food_drink": // do other stuff; break;
}
```

Comment: Richard you’re a god!!! thank you so much I've been stuck with this for 3 days!! really appreciate this sites support. I'm sure I'll be back adding my 2 pennies :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an object before `.val()` on both lines you use this.:

```
if ($("input[name='business_group']").attr("checked")==true && .val("accommodation")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
if ($("input[name='business_group']").prop("checked")==true && $("input[name='business_group']").val("accommodation")) {
```

If you are using a recent version of jQuery `attr` will not return a boolean value. It will return "checked" if the checkbox is checked or `undefined` if it is not checked. The `prop` function should give you a boolean value back. More info here - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: that's ipr101, the php is putting checked or unchecked into the page on refresh :)